# Spring Boot + Mockito - MockMvc lacking methods

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

i have this simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MainController.class)
public class MainControllerTest extends ControllerTest {


@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private Storage storage;

@MockBean
private PersonListMarshaller marshaller;


@Test
public void getTest() throws Exception{
    mvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("index"));
}

@Test
public void postTest() throws Exception{


}

}
```

in the postTest() method i wanna call: 
`mvc.perform(post("/")).param(...);` I have a problem with the "param()" part, because intelliJ Idea doesnt recognize that method. I've searched through the documentation and also doesn't found it. I've seen people using it in various spring-related sites though (and few other methods that are unavailable for me). Why can't i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `param` needs to be off of post. More specifically, `post` returns MockHttpServletRequestBuilder which has the `param` method. Should look like

```
mvc.perform(post("/").param("", ""))
    .andExpect(...)
```

Comment: Indeed. Didn't notice that.